# Show alert dialog from background process in any activity

Tags: java, android

How to get result of background process in any `Activity`?

I'm working with OTA update. App handle that in background with handler. When update is done I have to show alert dialog to the user. I can show it in `SettingsActivity` where I start with OTA but user can be in any other `Activity`.

```
private void checkIsUpdated() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDevice.getDevice().read(GattUUID.LS_DEVICE_INFORMATION, GattUUID.LC_FIRMWARE, new
                    BleDevice.ReadWriteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(ReadWriteEvent e) {
                            if (e.wasSuccess()) {

                                if (firmwareVersion.equals(e.data_string())) {
                                    showAlertDialog("OTA update failed", "Device is not updated");

                                } else {
                                    showAlertDialog("OTA update is successful.\nDevice is updated to new " +
                                            "firmware!", "Device is updated");

                                }

                                Log.i("OTA", "Read firmware is new success");
                            } else {
                                Log.e("OTA", "Read firmware is new success");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }, 30000);
}
```

`AlertDialog` code

```
 private void showAlertDialog(String message, String title) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.SwipeDialogLight);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    if (!alert.isShowing()) {
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried broadcast receiver for this?

Comment: I have to register it in every activity?

Comment: I guess just for an alert dialog ,only register it from splash screen of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @W4R10CK stated, I thought that too. The `BroadcastReceiver` might not a very good idea. But later, I gave a thought about it and if you call `checkIsUpdated` function inside a `Service` and send the `Broadcast` from it, it might be a feasible solution.

So basically you need a `BaseActivity` class and in which you need to have a `BroadcastReceiver`. You need to register it `onResume` and again unregister it `onPause`.

And you need to have an `abstract` method to be overriden in each of your `Activity` too.

So your `BaseActivity` may look like this..

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Context context;

    public BaseActivity() {
        this.context = setContext();
    }

    protected abstract Context setContext();

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unRegisterBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    // Declare your BroadcastReceiver here
    private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            showAlertDialog(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution, again BroadcastReciever is not a good idea to implement on thread, else if the background process is a service. Good solution.

Answer (score 2):

As @rogerwar suggested in the comments, the correct approach is a broadcast receiver.

Vogella has a nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Since you want to have it in all activities, you can make a base class for all your activities and in this base class you can register the receiver in the onStart and unregister it in the onStop.

Comment: Yes, BroadcastReciever is not a good idea from background process, else if the background process is service.

Comment: BroadcastReciever is a good idea to implement if the background process is Service, and it's not a good idea if implemented in thread.

Comment: @W4R10CK I think that if you are starting a thread, you can pass the reference to the currently activity. If you are doing a job in a thread that should be persisted between activities, I think that you should not use a thread.